# Is it possible to click on button and make that the another button or label are appear ?(iOS)

Tags: button, label

sorry for the stupid question, but how can I do that?
Or how can I do something like this

Comment: Yes it's possible. Make an attempt and come back when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure it's possible: (code below does not compile, but shows how things work)

```
UIButton *sender = ....;
id theOtherOne = .... ;//Button, Label, whatever
....
[sender addTarget:self action:@selector(changeTheOtherOne:)];


....

-(void)changeTheOtherOne:(id)sender
{
  [theOtherOne sendSomeMessage];
}
```